# What is the reverse of this Query in Postgres (the value not contained in this array)

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT fullobject 
FROM openidm.managedobjects m 
where  ('"d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996"' !=ANY (ARRAY(
  select * from json_array_elements(fullobject->'activeAccounts'))::text[]
))
```

Comment: explain more please!

Comment: `value != any(array)` means exactly what it says: value is not equal to **any** element of array. So, for example `1 != any(array[1,2])` is true because 1 != 2. The only case when condition will be false is when all elements of array are same end equal to value. Is it really what you want?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

**update**
My logic on `not not false` = `true` was flawfull here, I can't apply binary comparison for 2^2 field. Sorry my English, so the below is wrong:

```
SELECT fullobject 
FROM openidm.managedobjects m 
where NOT ('"d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996"' = ANY (ARRAY(
  select * from json_array_elements(fullobject->'activeAccounts'))::text[]
))
```

As Abelisto demonstrated:

```
with t(x,y) as (values(array[1,1],array[1,2])) select 1 != any(x) as x1, not 1 = any(x) as x2, 1 != any(y) as y1, not 1 = any(y) as y2 from t;
 x1 | x2 | y1 | y2
----+----+----+----
 f  | f  | t  | f
(1 row)
```

Comment: my bad - missed `=`

Comment: `with t(x,y) as (values(array[1,1],array[1,2])) select 1 != any(x) as x1, not 1 = any(x) as x2, 1 != any(y) as y1, not 1 = any(y) as y2 from t;` First two columns both false and second two columns are true and false respectively...

Comment: updated answer not to confuse people and included your "case matrix"

Answer (score 0):

Changed the Query operator != into <> and change keyword 'ANY' into 'ALL' eg:- `SELECT columnName 
FROM table m 
where  ('"value"' <> all (ARRAY(
  select * from json_array_elements(JsonKey in a Column))::text[]
))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need something like this:

```
SELECT fullobject 
FROM openidm.managedobjects m 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM json_array_elements(fullobject->'activeAccounts') AS j
      WHERE j::text ='"d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996"'
);
```

Or probably EXISTS instead NOT EXISTS.
This up to twice better than original query.

But if you can use jsonb it will be much more better:

```
SELECT fullobject 
FROM openidm.managedobjects m 
WHERE (fullobject->'activeAccounts') ?| ARRAY['d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996']::text[];
```

For more improving you can add index:

```
CREATE INDEX i1 ON openidm.managedobjects USING GIN ((fullobject->'activeAccounts'));
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE openidm.managedobjects (fullobject json);

INSERT INTO openidm.managedobjects (fullobject)
SELECT ('{"activeAccounts": ["'|| i || '"]}')::json
FROM generate_series(1, 100000) AS i ;

INSERT INTO openidm.managedobjects (fullobject) SELECT
('{"activeAccounts": ["d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996"]}')::json;
```

## Results:

#### Old query:

```
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on managedobjects m  (cost=0.00..104085.12 rows=99596 width=32) (actual time=0.044..282.382 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Filter: ('"d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996"'::text <> ANY (((SubPlan 1))::text[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Function Scan on json_array_elements  (cost=0.01..1.00 rows=100 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=100001)
 Planning time: 0.256 ms
 Execution time: 287.526 ms
(7 rows)
```

#### Json improved query:

```
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on managedobjects m  (cost=0.00..177405.44 rows=50048 width=32) (actual time=0.017..187.928 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Function Scan on json_array_elements j  (cost=0.01..1.76 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=100001)
           Filter: ((value)::text = '"d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996"'::text)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 0.098 ms
 Execution time: 193.503 ms
(9 rows)
```

#### Jsonb query:

```
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on managedobjects2 m  (cost=0.00..2839.36 rows=127 width=32) (actual time=31.887..31.888 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: ((fullobject -> 'activeAccounts'::text) ?| '{d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996}'::text[])
   Rows Removed by Filter: 100000
 Planning time: 0.039 ms
 Execution time: 31.901 ms
(5 rows)
```

#### jsonb with index:

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on managedobjects2 m  (cost=16.78..307.38 rows=100 width=32) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((fullobject -> 'activeAccounts'::text) ?| '{d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996}'::text[])
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i1  (cost=0.00..16.75 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((fullobject -> 'activeAccounts'::text) ?| '{d6df99ee334ab5c29b9585b82ffd650c19df6996}'::text[])
 Planning time: 0.122 ms
 Execution time: 0.030 ms
(7 rows)
```